# swipe using Tabbed activity

Tags: android, eclipse, swipe, tabactivity

I am a beginner at android programming and I'm using eclipse luna. I created a new activity and I chose Tabbed Activity instead of Blank activity. It already has codes with swiping. But there are codes that I cannot understand. I dont know how I can change the activity when I swipe. In the Case, I am wondering why it is string instead of the reference of the activity.

Here's the code from tabbed activity:

```
package com.e_learningforchildren.sarah;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TopicsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a {@link FragmentPagerAdapter}
 * derivative, which will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this
 * becomes too memory intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_topics);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.topics, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
        return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);

        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_topics,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are not swiping Activities you are just swiping a fragment and the string is your page title.

I think you should learn about fragments and how to manage then or replace them.

Adding you with the link
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Okay so its Activity not fragment. This what I did when I need to create a new activity: New>Other>Android Activity>Tabbed Activity>Done. I'm just confused because tabbed activity is written but fragment appeared after I chose Tabbed Activity.

Answer (score 1):

here is my code of swipe tabs with fragments
not included imports

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager viewpager;
    ActionBar actionbar;
    String[] tabs={"temperature","information"};
    tabpageadapter adapterm;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewpager=( ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

        actionbar=getActionBar();

        adapterm= new tabpageadapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewpager.setAdapter(adapterm);

        actionbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

       actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1F2230")));

       actionbar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#323445")));


        for(String tabb:tabs)
        {
            actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText(tabb).setTabListener(this));
        }


        viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);




    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

this is page adapter for viewpager

```
public class tabpageadapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

public tabpageadapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(index)

    {
    case 0:
        return new temperature_fragment();

    case 1:
        return new information_fragment();




    }


    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 2;
}

}
```

these is a fragment file just create another one with diff name so 2 tabs will be availble

```
public class temperature_fragment extends Fragment{

    TextView tvtemp,farenhit;


    LinearLayout llfortemp;
    Intent inte;

    BatteryManager bm;
    double i,j;
    int l,k;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.temperature_xml, container,false);


        Context cc=getActivity();

        tvtemp=(TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.texttemp);
        farenhit=(TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.textViewfarenhit);
        llfortemp=(LinearLayout)rootview.findViewById(R.id.llfortemp);






        return rootview;
    }











        }
```

Comment: I searched about swiping and there are lots of ways to do it. Thanks for your codes, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just starting, I don't recommend going with the Swiping example first, the swipe is for "Fragment"s not "Activity" which is pretty advanced subject if you're a beginner in Android development.

I'd recommend that you go through this tutorial as it will teach you all you need to know about Activities, Fragments, Actionbars, Menus, Layout components, ... etc. Eventually you'll have a solid basis that you just need to build on top of. (Ignore the parts about command line since you're using Eclipse).

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: I did another research and yes it is fragment and not activity. Thanks for the link,it is big help. @NightwareSystems